# SpringMVC で エラー以外のメッセージを表示する方法について

Tags: spring

SpringではValidationやServiceで発生したエラーの情報をBindingResultにセットさせ、
JSPで`<form:errors>`で内容を表示できると思うのですが

Strutsでは`<html:message>`でメッセージを出力していたのですが、エラーメッセージ以外のメッセージを表示しようとしたらどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

[What is the equivalent of Struts ActionMessages in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536723/2322778)

※リンク先を見る限りエラー以外のメッセージを出力するには自身で仕組みを作る必要があるのかなぁ・・・と思うのですがそうなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> エラーメッセージ以外のメッセージを表示しようとしたらどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

[SPR-2657](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-2657)の最初のコメントにあるように、`ModelAndView`を使用するのが一般的なのではないでしょうか。

例えば、登録後の成功メッセージであれば、次のように`Controller`で`ModelAndView`にメッセージを追加(`addObject`)して、

```
mav.addObject("success_message", msg.getMessage("registration.successfully.completed", null, locale));
```

テンプレートで、それらしいスタイルを付けて表示する、とか（※ちなみに以下は、ThymeleafとBootstrapを使用した例です）。

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><p th:text="${success_message}" /></div>
```

[SPR-2657](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-2657)の詳細を見ると、ResolutionがDuplicateで、StatusがClosedになっています。
Duplicate(重複)した問題というのは、[SPR-6464](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6464)のようなので、Springの開発者はこれが解決策となると考えて、この問題をクローズしたのだと思います。[SPR-6464](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6464)の「フラッシュスコープ」で要件を満たせるかも、検討してみて下さい。

Comment: やはり、ModelAndViewを利用するのが一般的なのですね・・・SPR-6464のフラッシュスコープにメッセージを使う件はredirect時にのみ有効で、データの削除を自動でしてくれると言う認識であってるでしょうか？SPRの内容を読んでいるとやはりメッセージをいっきに出力するタグは存在しないということですね・・・。

Comment: はい。そういうことですかね。存在しないと言い切るのは難しいですが...